# While i'm installing egit plugin in eclipse i was getting errors

Tags: eclipse

****Problems occurred while performing provisioning operation: Profile id *SELF* is not registered.
Profile id *SELF* is not registered.****

Comment: which system do you use? MacOS?

Comment: No, iam not using MacOs i'm using Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add P2 repository to product. A little late but...